# eager loading a small subset of all has_many objects based on conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I eager-load only some of the objects in a has_many relationship?

Basically, I have four objects: `Assignment`, `Problem`, `AssignmentUser`, and `ProblemUser`.

```
#assignment.rb
has_many :problems
has_many :assignment_users

#assignment_user.rb
belongs_to :assignment
belongs_to :user
has_many :problem_users

#problem.rb
belongs_to :assignment
has_many :problem_users

#problem_user.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :problem
belongs_to :assignment_user
attr_accessor :complete #boolean
```

On a page showing a single assignment, I want to show all of the problems, as well the user's status on each problem, if it exists.  (It might not, if this is the first time the user is viewing the page.)

I can't call `assignment_user.problem_users` and then snake the problems out like so:

```
-@assignment_user.problem_users.each do |problem_user|
    = check_box_tag "problems[#{problem_user.problem.id}]", 1, problem_user.complete
    = link_to problem_user.problem.name, assignment_problem_path(assignment_id => problem_user.problem.assignment_id, :id => problem_user.problem_id)
```

because there might not be `ProblemUser` entries for every `Problem` that belongs to an assignment; creating all of those `ProblemUser` objects whenever someone creates a `Problem` object would be wasteful, so they're only created on the fly.

What I want is to be able to iterate over the `Problems` that belong to the particular `Assignment`, then for each `Problem`, find a `ProblemUser` that matches...but without creating an N+1 problem.  I could create two arrays, one with all of the problems and one with all of the problem_users, but then I would have to match them up, right?  Maybe that's the best way... but any recommendations on best practices are appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **:include** something along the lines of...

```
#assignment.rb
has_many :problems, :include => :problem_user
has_many :assignment_users
```

Assuming a field named description in each of the tables assignments, problems, and problem_users the solution should resemble this...

```
Assignment.find(1).problems.collect { |a| [a.assignment.description, a.description, a.problem_user.description] }
```